# Render 3D model in orthographic mode (on top of a GUI)

Tags: opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I'm trying to render a GUI with some models on it (If you know Minecraft: I want to have the model like you see the model of the player in the inventory). I tried to render it in orthographic mode but nothing did appear. I try it like following:

```
        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslatef(guiX, guiY, 0f);

        item.render();

        glPopMatrix();
```

The item is calling a model to render. This model is stored in an VBO and the rendering works in the non-orthographic mode. Can't I render 3D models in ortho mode?

Heres is how I enter ortho mode:

```
public static void enterOrtho() {
    glPushAttrib(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glPushMatrix();

    // now enter orthographic projection
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -100, 100);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

public static void leaveOrtho() {
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopAttrib();
}
```

I did try to not disable GL_DEPTH_TEST but nothing did happen either.

Comment: Don't forget to clear the Z-buffer before drawing the ortho model ...

Comment: The question is stated very poorly. You are drawing some unspecified object with unknown object coordinates and unknown transformations. It is impossible to find the exact problem, but it is highly likely that you just draw outside of the viewing volume.

Comment: Well I don't think I'm drawing outside since I start using a new matrix. The coordinates of the GUI are also known and are used to place the gui in the center of the screen, so this is the only transformation which is done here. In item.render only the VBO is drawn. I also tried clearing the depth (or z) buffer now but it didn't help. I added some code of my Ortho initialisations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was solved... It seems to really have been outside the screen :/